# Using the method of Lagrange multipliers, find the extreme values of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers, find the extreme values of the function
$f(x,y)= \frac{2y^3}{3} + 2x^2 +1$ on the ellipse $5x^2 + y^2 = 1/9$
 . Identify the (absolute) maximal and minimal values of f
taken on the ellipse.

currently I have that $\nabla f(x,y)=L*\nabla g(x,y)$ where $g(x,y)=5x^2 + y^2-1/9$

this leads to: $4x-10Lx=0$, so $x=0$ or $L=2/5$

and:$2y^2-2Ly=0$, so $y=0$ or $y=L$.

where do I go from here? andy help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The only solutions that make sense are $ \ (0, Y) \ , \ (X, 0) \ , \ \text{or} \ (X', \frac{2}{5} ) \ $ as points on the ellipse.  (Where _does_ that "9" go in the equation for the ellipse?  You have two different expressions as this stands.)  You would then compare the values for the function.

Comment: ahh my apologies made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 4x= \gamma\cdot 10x$, and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y^2 = \gamma\cdot 2y$. So: $2x(2 - 5\gamma) = 0$, and $2y(y - \gamma) = 0$. So

case 1: $x = 0$, so $y^2 = \dfrac{1}{9}$. So $y = \dfrac{1}{3}$ or $-\dfrac{1}{3}$. So:
$f(0,\frac{1}{3}) = \dfrac{83}{81}$, and $f(0,-\frac{1}{3}) = \dfrac{79}{81}$

case 2: $x \neq 0$, and $\gamma = \dfrac{2}{5}$, and $y = 0$ or $y = \dfrac{2}{5}$. If $y = 0$, then $x = \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}$ or $x = -\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}$, and in both cases $f(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}, 0) = \dfrac{47}{45}$. If $y = \dfrac{2}{5}$, then $5x^2 = -\dfrac{12}{225} < 0$, and there is no solution in this case.

So: $f_{min} = \dfrac{79}{81} = 0.975$, and $f_{max} = \dfrac{47}{45} = 1.044$

Comment: We have the interesting situation in this problem that the Lagrange-multiplier method indicates a solution ($ \ \lambda  =  \frac{2}{5} \ $ ) which fails to occur because the "level curve" for $ \ 5x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = c \ $ is insufficiently large to have a tangent point with coordinate $ \ y \ = \ \lambda \ $ .

Answer (score 0):

Also differentiate wrt L, which just gives you your constraint back.  Take the solutions x=0 and y=L and put into constraint to get L=1/3, and so y=1/3.