# using the method of LaGrange multipliers find the extreme values of the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

using the method of LaGrange multipliers find the extreme values of the function

$f(x,y)=x^3+4y^2$ with constraint $x^2+y^2=1$

currently I have that: $3x^2=2Lx$ which leads to $x=0$ or $L=3/2$

and: $8y=2Ly$ which leads to $L=4$ or $y=0$

using the constraint when $x=0$ $y=+/-1$ which leads to $f(0,+/-1)=4$

using the constraint when $y=0$ $x=+/-1$ which leads to $f(+/-1,0)=1$

where do I go from here it seems that $f(0,+/-1)=4$ is a maximum and $f(+/-1,0)=1$ is a minimum, and what is the significance of L since we never use it? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Type \$\pm\$ to render $\pm$ and \$\dfrac {a}{b}\$ to render $\dfrac a b$.

Comment: I got $(0,\pm 1)$ and $(\pm 1, 0)$ only. I also don't know exactly what you mean with "the significance of $L$", but perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Interpretation_of_the_Lagrange_multipliers) helps.

Answer (score 1):

A possible source of confusion here as to the use of the Lagrange multiplier $ \ \lambda \ $ appears to be due to the first Lagrange equation being factored incorrectly.  The two equations are found properly, but we should have

$$ 3x^2 \ - \ 2 \lambda \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ ( \ 3x \ - \ 2 \lambda \ ) \ = \ 0 \ \ ,  $$

$$  8y \ - \ 2 \lambda \ y \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2y \ ( \ 4 \ - \ \lambda \ ) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

So two of the possible solution sets are correctly given as $ \ ( 0 , \ \pm 1 ) \ $ and $ \ ( \pm 1, \ 0) \ $ by applying the constraint equation.

However, there *is* only the only value for the Lagrange multiplier found from the second equation, $ \ \lambda \ = \ 4 \ $ .  This would be applied in the second factor of the first equation to obtain

$$  3x \ - \ 2 \lambda \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ x \ = \ \frac{2  \cdot  4}{3} \ = \ \frac{8}{3} \ \ .  $$

This raises an interesting issue in problems of this sort.  In this case, the result produced by using the Lagrange multiplier value is inapplicable because there are no points with $ \ x \ = \ \frac{8}{3} \ $ on the constraint surface.  [A similar circumstance arises in [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770411/using-the-method-of-lagrange-multipliers-find-the-extreme-values-of-a-function/770434#comment1600658_770434).] Therefore, the extremal values of our function are

$$ f(0, \ \pm 1) \ = \ 4 \ \ [\text{absolute maximum}] \ \ ; $$

$$ f(1, \ 0) \ = \ 1 \ \ [\text{local maximum}] \ \ ; $$

$$ f(-1, \ 0) \ = \ -1 \ \ [\text{absolute minimum}] \ \ . $$

The "geometric" interpretation of this result is that the values for the function represent maximum and minimum values of the $ \ z-$ coordinate of the possible intersection points of the surface $ \ z \ = \ f(x,y) \ = \ x^3 \ + \ 4y^2 \ $ with the "vertical" cylinder $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ 1 \ $ .

[image]

*We show two views of the intersecting surfaces, with three of the four "critical points" visible; $ \ (0, \ -1, \ 4) \ $ is on the "far side" of the diagram at left.*

$$ \ \ $$

The value found for the multiplier is the same regardless of the radius of that cylinder, which suggests that the coordinate $ \ x \ = \ \frac{8}{3} \ $ could *become* important if the constraint surface were "larger".  If we were to use the cylinder $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ 9 \ $ as the constraint "surface", for instance, our result from the Lagrange multiplier would be applicable, now giving us extremal values

$$ f(0, \ \pm 3) \ = \ 36 \ \ [\text{absolute maximum}] \ \ ; $$

$$ f(3, \ 0) \ = \ 27 \ \ [\text{local maximum}] \ \ ; $$

$$ f(-3, \ 0) \ = \ -27 \ \ [\text{absolute minimum}] \ \ ; $$

$$ f\left(\frac{8}{3}, \ \pm \frac{\sqrt{17}}{3}\right) \ = \ \frac{716}{27} \ \approx \ 26.52 \ \ [\text{local minima}] \ \ . $$

For these larger cylindrical radii, the intersection with the surface $ \ f(x,y) \ $ along the "positive $ -x \ $ " face of the cylinder develops a "ripple", leading to the appearance of further "critical points" with $ \ x \ = \ \frac{8}{3} \ $ .

[image]

*The somewhat more complicated shape of the intersection of the surfaces is visible in the left-hand graph; the critical point $ \ (0, \ -3, \ 36) \ $ is not visible in these views.*